# Locking cell groups

Tags: notebooks, distributions, security, notebook-security

Imagine I have a notebook divided into multiple groups of code cells which are set as initialization groups. I then have a single cell which evaluates a function `program[]` that yields an interactive tool (for example via `Manipulate`) which internal functions are defined in the initialization groups. Something like

[image]

If these groups are collapsed, is it possible to lock them so that when I share the notebook the code in these groups remains hidden and private and the only accessible cell is the one to run the program?

Comment: Have you considered moving the code into a package file (`.wl`)? Also, what do you mean by "hidden and private"? If the user needs to be able to execute it, they need to have read access to the code in some way.

Comment: No, I don't know much about packages. The simplest thing is perhaps to imagine that I define my function `program` in some cell within an initialization group, so that when I run the cell with `program[]`, it first evaluates the group cells, defining `program`, and then shows me only the output of this last cell. All I'm asking is whether it is possible to lock the group and let initialization cells do the automatic work without needing to see any of the code in it.

Comment: It would be very practical if I could do this, but perhaps moving it into a package is a better option.

Comment: You might be able to use cell tags to mark certain cells as password protected and then use one of the `$Pre` variables, or `CellProlog` or something to lock the use of the hide/expand button. I don't know how you'd implement that though. Obviously you still need a way to access the stuff in the cell yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the `status` flag of the [`CellGroupData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellGroupData.html) of your cells to `Dynamic[False, None]`. This prevents any interactive opening of the cells. If you then also set [`ShowGroupOpener`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShowGroupOpener.html) to `False`, it seems somewhat workable:

```
CreatePalette@Row@{
   Button["Lock",
    NotebookWrite[
     InputNotebook[],
     NotebookRead[InputNotebook[]] /.
      CellGroupData[cells_, _] :> CellGroupData[cells, Dynamic[False, None]],
     All
     ];
    SetOptions[#, ShowGroupOpener -> False] & /@ Cells@NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]]
    ],
   Button["Unlock",
    NotebookWrite[
     InputNotebook[],
     NotebookRead[InputNotebook[]] /.
      CellGroupData[cells_, _] :> CellGroupData[cells, False],
     All
     ];
    SetOptions[#, ShowGroupOpener -> Inherited] & /@ Cells@NotebookSelection[InputNotebook[]]
    ]
   }
```

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you so much